# How get all values in a column using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I've been searching for this everywhere, but still can't find a solution: How do I get all the values from a mySQL column and store them in an array?

For eg: 
 Table Name: Customers
 Column names: ID, Name
 # of rows: 5

I want to get an array of all the 5 names in this table. How do I go about doing that? I am using PHP, and I was trying to just:

```
SELECT names FROM Customers
```

and then use the

```
mysql_fetch_array
```

PHP function to store those values in an array.

Comment: Notice: most answers still use the old MySQL functions, these functions where deprecated in PHP 5, and removed in PHP 7, I suggest you change the accepted answer to one that works in the latest PHP

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> **Note that this answer is outdated!** The mysql extension is no longer available out of the box as of PHP7. If you want to use the old mysql functions in PHP7, [you will have to compile ext/mysql from PECL.](https://ckon.wordpress.com/2015/08/06/put-mysql-functions-back-into-php-7/) See the other answers for more current solutions.

---

This would work, see more documentation here :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT names FROM Customers");
$storeArray = Array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $storeArray[] =  $row['names'];  
}
// now $storeArray will have all the names.
```

Comment: Hey! This answer to this popular question breaks in PHP 7 because `mysql_*` is no longer supported. Could you edit this so that it uses the more modern APIs (PDO or MySQLi)? Alternatively, would you object other people to edit this information in?

Answer (score 35):

Here is a simple way to do this using either [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT Column FROM foo");
// careful, without a LIMIT this can take long if your table is huge
$stmt->execute();
$array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
print_r($array);
```

or, using mysqli

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Column FROM foo");
$stmt->execute();
$array = [];
foreach ($stmt->get_result() as $row)
{
    $array[] = $row['column'];
}
print_r($array);
```

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7960
    [1] => 7972
    [2] => 8028
    [3] => 8082
    [4] => 8233
)
```

Comment: best answer really (2020 version) ... année ou je code beaucoup finalement :)

Comment: Don't we all @Yves :)

Answer (score 5):

I would use a mysqli connection to connect to the database. Here is an example:

```
$connection = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "username", "password", "database_name", 3306);
```

The next step is to select the information. In your case I would do:

```
$query = $connection->query("SELECT `names` FROM `Customers`;");
```

And finally we make an array from all these names by typing:

```
$array = Array();
while($result = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    $array[] = $result['names'];
}

print_r($array);
```

So what I've done in this code:
I selected all names from the table using a mysql query. Next I use a while loop to check if the $query has a next value. If so the while loop continues and adds that value to the array '$array'. Else the loop stops. And finally I print the array using the 'print_r' method so you can see it all works. I hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Since **mysql_*** are deprecated, so here is the solution using **mysqli**.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');
if($mysqli->connect_errno>0)
{
  die("Connection to MySQL-server failed!"); 
}
$resultArr = array();//to store results
//to execute query
$executingFetchQuery = $mysqli->query("SELECT `name` FROM customers WHERE 1");
if($executingFetchQuery)
{
   while($arr = $executingFetchQuery->fetch_assoc())
   {
        $resultArr[] = $arr['name'];//storing values into an array
   }
}
print_r($resultArr);//print the rows returned by query, containing specified columns
```

There is another way to do this using **PDO**

```
  $db = new PDO('mysql:host=host_name;dbname=db_name', 'username', 'password'); //to establish a connection
  //to fetch records
  $fetchD = $db->prepare("SELECT `name` FROM customers WHERE 1");
  $fetchD->execute();//executing the query
  $resultArr = array();//to store results
  while($row = $fetchD->fetch())
  {
     $resultArr[] = $row['name'];
  }
  print_r($resultArr);
```

Comment: that won't be making an array of just *one* value for all the rows in the table, it will be an array of all the *rows* selected (a multi-dimensional array instead of a two-dimensional array)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I've misread the sentence **For eg: Table Name: Customers Column names: ID, Name # of rows: 5** that is why added `id` and `name` in my answer. But now, I have corrected it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7

Use array_column on the result array

```
$column = array_column($result, 'names');
```

Answer (score -1):

[How to put MySQL functions back into PHP 7](https://ckon.wordpress.com/2015/08/06/put-mysql-functions-back-into-php-7/)
**Step 1**

First get the mysql extension source which was removed in March:

https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/PRE_PHP7_EREG_MYSQL_REMOVALS/ext/mysql

**Step 2**

Then edit your php.ini

Somewhere either in the “Extensions” section or “MySQL” section, simply add this line:

```
extension = /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20141001/mysql.so
```

**Step 3**

Restart PHP and mysql_* functions should now be working again.

**Step 4**

Turn off all deprecated warnings including them from mysql_*:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

**Now Below Code Help You :**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT names FROM Customers");
$Data= Array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
        $Data[] =  $row['names'];  
}
```

You can also get all values in column using `mysql_fetch_assoc`

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT names FROM Customers");
    $Data= Array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
            $Data[] =  $row['names'];  
    }
```

> This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

---

**YOU CAN USE MYSQLI ALTERNATIVE OF MYSQL EASY WAY**

---

*

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="SELECT Lastname,Age FROM Persons ORDER BY Lastname";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

// Numeric array
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
printf ("%s (%s)\n",$row[0],$row[1]);

// Associative array
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf ("%s (%s)\n",$row["Lastname"],$row["Age"]);

// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Hey there! While this answer effectively allows you to continue using mysql, **there is a reason why it was removed!!!!!** one should stop using it and refactor his code with parameterized queries.

Comment: yes @FélixGagnon-Grenier you are right.that's why i also put other easy way connect with database using "Mysqli"....thanks

Answer (score -1):

First things is this is only for advanced developers persons Who all are now beginner to php dont use this function if you are using the huge project in core php use this function

```
function displayAllRecords($serverName, $userName, $password, $databaseName,$sqlQuery='')
{
    $databaseConnectionQuery =  mysqli_connect($serverName, $userName, $password, $databaseName);
    if($databaseConnectionQuery === false)
    {
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
        return false;
    }

    $resultQuery = mysqli_query($databaseConnectionQuery,$sqlQuery);
    $fetchFields = mysqli_fetch_fields($resultQuery);
    $fetchValues = mysqli_fetch_fields($resultQuery);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultQuery) > 0) 
    {           

        echo "<table class='table'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($fetchFields as $fetchedField)
         {          
            echo "<td>";
            echo "<b>" . $fetchedField->name . "<b></a>";
            echo "</td>";
        }       
        echo "</tr>";
        while($totalRows = mysqli_fetch_array($resultQuery)) 
        {           
            echo "<tr>";                                
            for($eachRecord = 0; $eachRecord < count($fetchValues);$eachRecord++)
            {           
                echo "<td>";
                echo $totalRows[$eachRecord];
                echo "</td>";               
            }
            echo "<td><a href=''><button>Edit</button></a></td>";
            echo "<td><a href=''><button>Delete</button></a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";           
        } 
        echo "</table>";        

    } 
    else
    {
      echo "No Records Found in";
    }
}
```

All set now Pass the arguments as For `Example`

$queryStatment = "SELECT * From USERS ";
$testing = displayAllRecords('localhost','root','root@123','email',$queryStatment);
echo $testing;

Here

`localhost` indicates Name of the `host`,

`root` indicates the username for `database`

`root@123` indicates the `password for the database`

`$queryStatment` for `generating Query`

hope it helps