# MySQLi query stops at first item in a column when I need all items

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to get all the `image_name` values from one of my tables where the `category` and `account_id` match.
The query joins 3 tables.

I am using mysqli.

```
SELECT image_name 
FROM add_images, item, user_item
WHERE user_item.account_id = '$accountId' AND item.category = '$category';
```

However when this query executes and `var_dump()` the result,  I find only the first record?  there should be 8 items?

I have confirmed this by returning `count()` on the array which returned 1.

If I run this query in phpmyadmin the query runs successfully and it finds all 8 items, however they are repeated 8 times, not sure what that is about?

I have replaced `image_name` with `*` also I have tried `image_name.*` and `image_name*` all fail in my code and in phpmyadmin.

When I dump out the object I get:

```
object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(512) ["type"]=> int(0) } int(1) string(29)
```

I have also tried the following suggested in:
    [How get all values in a column using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229501/get-all-values-in-a-column-using-php)

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

but the suggested code also fails.

Below is my code:

```
public function searchItems($accountId, $catagory,$userId){
    $imagePath = "D:\imagesdb\images\\" . $userId;
    $thumb_path = $imagePath . "t\\";
    $conn = $this->create_connection('read');
    $sql = "SELECT image_name FROM add_images, item, user_item WHERE user_item.account_id='$accountId' AND item.catagory='$catagory'"; 
    $result = $conn->query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
    var_dump($result);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $path = $thumb_path . $row['image_name'];
        $result = count($path);
        var_dump($result);
        return $path;
    }
    $conn->close();
}
```

I have also tried a prepared statement I have the same issue which I expected!

Does anyone have any suggestions please? This has been driving me mad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning $path unconditionally in the while-loop. So the function returns after it has fetched one row. This is probably not what you intended.

You probably want to create an array, add all image paths to that and return the array at the end of the function.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, yes this is not what i intended! I have modified my code problem is it still returns one item             $path = array();
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $path = $thumb_path . $row['image_name'];
   }
   return $path;
   $conn->close();
  }

Comment: replace `$path = ...` with `$path[] = ...` in the while loop. otherwise you are just replacing the array with the current value instead of adding elements to it.

Comment: argh! thank you so much! it works any idea why items are repeated tho?

Comment: You're welcome. Duplicate items you not happen, check the SQL for errors again or just use `array_unique`.

Comment: I will look into this thanks again for your help, much appricated