# The database returns only the first row instead of column

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to obtain a column name EmailId from the table named Users. But it returns only the first string and nothing else?

PHP:

```
$sql="SELECT EmailId FROM Users;";
$result =mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$col=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

The database has 3 email-ids but `count($col)` returns only 1. Why so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because there is only one column in the array returned by `mysqli_fetch_array()`. Read the manual to learn how these functions actually work.

Comment: So how can I get the column in an array?

Comment: To get the first value: $row = mysql_fetch_row($result); echo $row[0];

Comment: I mean all the rows in a column?

Comment: You need to do a better job explaining what you're looking for. If you mean all of your results, you need to loop through the results. Once again, read the manual as it shows you how to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get all values in a column using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229501/get-all-values-in-a-column-using-php)

Answer (score 1):

> The database has 3 email-ids but count($col) returns only 1. Why so?

Because

```php
$col=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

only fetch the first row according to the internal pointer of the dataset, and therefore

```php
count($col)
```

returns 1 because `$col` is an array having 1 item.